# polyfit and polyval funtions

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Hello my question is about curve tiffing of P3(x) I write my code with using polyfit and polyval functions but I need to make it without using these functions.

this is my code that I wrote

```
n=input('Enter a value: ');
if(n<3)
    fprintf('Enter a different value larger than 3')
end 
if(n>=3)
x = 1:n; 
y = -0.3*x + 2*randn(1,n); 
[p,S] = polyfit(x,y,3);
[y_fit,delta] = polyval(p,x,S);
plot(x,y,'bo')
hold on
plot(x,y_fit,'r-')
title('Linear-Fit Output')
legend('Data','Linear Fit')
end
```

this is code that I write it is working but I am suppose to write it without using polfite and polyval functions

Comment: Is this school work?

Comment: yes sir. It is my homework and lecturer is not let us to use these functions he said it today but deadline is tomorrow

Comment: I add my work in the question and I am still trying to implement it.

Comment: Please consult the above duplicate - Simply change the `degree` variable to 3 instead of 8 as seen in the post.  It also has the advantage that it does not use the Symbolic Math Toolbox.  Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070670/matlab-curve-fitting-least-squares-method-wrong-fit-using-high-degrees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without Using `syms`**

```
y = a0*x^0 + a1*x^1 + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3
For n data point --> y = X*a
```

where

```
X = [x1^0 , a1*x1^1, a2*x1^2 , a3*x1^3; x2^0 , a1*x2^1, a2*x2^2 , a3*x2^3;...;xn^0 , a1*xn^1 , a2*xn^2 , a3*xn^3 ]
```

and `a = [a0, a1, a2, a3]; y = [y1, y2, ..., yn]`
a is computed as follow

```
y = X*a ---> a = X\y
```

**The code is as follows**

```
n is given 
x = 1:n; 
y = -0.3*x + 2*randn(1,n);
x0 = ones(n, 1);
x1 = x';
x2 = (x.^2)';
x3 = (x.^3)';
X = [x0 x1 x2 x3];
a = X\(y');
f =@(t)a(1) + a(2).*t + a(3).*(t.^2)+ a(4).*(t.^3);
```

**Use least square method to find best fit cubic polynomial**

```
n=input('Enter a value: ');
if(n<3)
    fprintf('Enter a different value larger than 3')
else
    x = 1:n; 
    y = -0.3*x + 2*randn(1,n);
    % Cubic regression

    syms a0 a1 a2 a3

    yq = a0 + a1.*x + a2.*(x.^2) + a3.*(x.^3) ;
    rq = yq - y;
    f = sum(rq.^2);
    fa0 = diff(f,a0);
    fa1 = diff(f,a1);
    fa2 = diff(f,a2);
    fa3 = diff(f,a3);
    sol = solve(fa0 == 0, fa1 == 0, fa2 == 0, a0, a1, a2, a3);
    a0 = sol.a0;
    a1 = sol.a1;
    a2 = sol.a2;
    a3 = sol.a3;

    % Cubic Regression  Curve Function

    f =@(t)a0 + a1.*t + a2.*(t.^2)+ a3.*(t.^3);

    % Plot Data and Cubic Regression Curve
    h = figure(1);
    % Data
    plot3 = scatter(x, y, 100, '+', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'red', 'linewidth', 5);
    hold on
    % cubic Regression Curve
    xx = linspace(0,n,100);
    plot4 = plot(xx, f(xx), 'linewidth', 5);
    [~,b] = legend([plot3 plot4],{'Real Data','Cubic Regression'}, 'FontSize',30);
    set(findobj(b,'-property','MarkerSize'),'MarkerSize',30);

    xlabel('x-axis','color', 'k', 'fontSize', 25)
    ylabel('y-axis', 'color','k', 'fontSize', 25)
    hYLabel = get(gca,'YLabel');
    set(hYLabel,'rotation',0,'VerticalAlignment','middle',  'HorizontalAlignment','right')
    grid on
    grid minor
    set(gca,'FontSize',20)
    set(get(h,'CurrentAxes'),'GridAlpha',0.8,'MinorGridAlpha',0.5);
    xticks(x);
    title('Cubic Regression', 'color', 'r');
    whitebg('w');
end
```

[image]

n = 5

---

[image]

n = 20

---

Comment: Can you propose a solution that **doesn't** use the Symbolic Math Toolbox?

Comment: I added method not using sym above.

Comment: This is pretty bad: `a = inv(transpose(X)*X)*transpose(X)*y`  You're reinventing the wheel, and not even doing it right.  Matlab has a pseudoinverse function `pinv` which correctly uses conjugate-transpose.  But you don't even need that, because a left-divide is completely sufficient.  `A = X \ y`  It's faster than computing an inverse as well as doing something more sensible when faced with degenerate inputs.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is just a pseudocode to show what data is need to compute a. Check just right  below in the code format, I write  a = ((X')*X)\((X')*(y'));

Comment: That's got the conjugate-transpose right, but still is not as efficient or robust as `a = X \ y'`

Comment: @BenVoigt I updated my answer, thanks for the remark.